# Dynamic OnClick in IE, Safari, Firefox

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I have the following bit of code.  I'm trying to dynamically add drop-down options to a second drop-down based on the selection in a first drop-down.  Both are generated through an Ajax call to a script that pulls the data from a database.  Here is the relevant code.

```
 function setSub(doc) {
  // Setup some variables
  var sNode = document.getElementById('4'); // GRAB THE ELEMENT HERE
  var rmiData = doc.getElementById('rmiData').innerHTML;
  var aItems = rmiData.split("|");
  var aVals;
  // Set some background
  sNode.style.background = "#fff";
  // Loop through adding options to the drop down
  for (var x = 0; x < (aItems.length -1); x ++) {
   aVals = aItems[x].split("=");
   // ADD OPTIONS DYNAMICALLY TO SECOND DROP-DOWN HERE
   sNode.options[x+1] = new Option(aVals[1],aVals[0],false,false);
   // PROBLEM HERE: ADD ONCLICK TO THE OPTION WE JUST CREATED
   sNode.options[x+1].onclick = function() { fixDayList(); };
   //sNode.options[x+1].onclick = new Function("fixDayList();");
   //sNode.options[x+1].setAttribute("onclick", "fixDayList();");
   // END PROBLEM LINES
  }
  // Set the length
  sNode.length = x+1;
  // Select the first item in the list
  sNode[0].selected = true;
 }
```

If you notice the section after the "// PROBLEM HERE" line, I've tried to add the onclick event in three different ways.  All 3 work correctly in Firefox.  None of the 3 work in IE6 or Safari (Not sure on IE8).  Any suggestions for this?  The rest of the code is using some old-schoolish JavaScript that I copied from an existing piece of legacy code that works and I'm just trying to add onclick to my version (preferably without re-writing a lot of code).

Any thoughts on why the onclick events don't fire from Safari and IE?

I do have access to jQuery in my code. So, if jQuery fixes this internally and I can figure out the proper selector to use, that would work.  But, I'm not sure how to select this, exactly.  I tried:

$('#4').options[x+1].click( function() { fixDayList(); } );

But that selector is bad and I'm not sure exactly how to select the right one (I'm green in the ways of jQuery).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
if(window.addEventListener){
   sNode.options[x+1].addEventListener('click', fixDayList, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent){
   sNode.options[x+1].attachEvent('onclick', fixDayList);
} else {
   sNode.options[x+1].onclick = fixDayList;
}
```

**Update**:

In Safari, unless the `option` elements are visible and not displayed as a dropdown list, they will never trigger a `click` event. But, if you add `size=10` or whatever to your `select` element, Safari will then trigger click events on the `option` elements.

Your best bet will be to listen for the `change` event on the `select` element instead of trying to use `click` on the `options`.

Comment: That also worked in Firefox (so now I have 4 different solutions that work in Firefox) but it doesn't work in IE or Safari.

Comment: @Joel, Safari won't trigger `click` events on an option element that is displayed as a drop down. I am not sure about IE, but I think it is the same thing. Sorry for the confusion in my answer, but I just tested and that is how it works (in Safari at least). I updated my answer.

Comment: Your right.  I'm doing this the wrong way.  I need to code this so that it fires "onChange" of the drop-down instead of "onClick" of the options. <<Slaps Forehead>>